# Connecting network drives when connected to a particular wired / wifi network

Tags: windows-7, networking

As stated in the title, i'm looking for a piece of software that could automagically connect some network drives when i'm connecting to some particular wifi (or wired) network.

Google wasn't of any help for that matter.

Is there anything able to handle this ?

Requirements:

- Windows 7
- Supports CIFS protocol
- Below 100 USD

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you use CIFS for your network drives? What is your budget?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Windows 7 as tagged in the question. I'm guessing it's CIFS since drives are on windows systems, but it would be a plus if it could handle other systems. About budget it really depends if it does the thing well or not but i think above 2 digits would be too much for something like this.